# eliminar producto de tabla producto que esta relacionada con nota de venta

Tags: php, mysql, sql, oracle

hola soy novato en programación web  y bd acabo de terminar mi primera pagina web en mis practica profesionales y la empresa quedo satisfecha, solo mi pregunta es por ejemplo yo tengo mi BD la cual tiene  una tabla productos relacionada con una tabla nota de venta, la duda en concreto si es correcto eliminar el producto de mi tabla productos o solo lo puedo darlo de baja , ya que como mi tabla nota esta relacionada con productos no se si cause algun error o que pasa con aquella notas de venta que ya son viejas y tiene asociado un producto que ya no esta en venta que se hace en esos caso se tiene que eliminar el producto de mi tabla producto permanente mente o solo agrego un campo en mi tabla producto que se llame activo o inactivo para que no se muestre  si es que ya no se desea vender en un futuro ese producto saludos!

Comment: la idea es hacer un borrado lógico mas no físico; me explico solo deberías pasar los datos de activos a inactivos; el eliminado permanente vuelve irrelevante el uso del software en si mismo por que deja de existir información con la cual trabajar de manera posterior

Comment: Hola. Lo más recomendable es crear una columna de activo, para verificar si el producto está o no disponible (no confundir con si hay stock o no), aunque esto también dependería de la forma y que tipo de información guardas den las notas de venta, si dichas notas tienen una id del producto que se ha vendido es más que recomendable no borrar los productos, ya que aunque en el futuro no se vendan si necesitas verificar una de esas notas y saber que productos se vendieron podrás hacerlo sin problema.

Comment: Buenas, no obstante, si tienes una relación entre productos y notas de venta, a menos que concretes que en el borrado de productos se borren los datos asociados a ese producto, la base de datos no te dejará borrarlo, ya que si defines una foreign key el campo referenciado siempre debe existir para el campo que toma el valor ese.

Comment: Este es uno de los casos en los que se deben romper las formas normales, una tabla de ventas (y/o detalles_ventas) deberia contener directamente los datos sin depender de otras tablas que puedan variar en el tiempo, es un poco largo de explicar y falta informacion de la implementacion de BD para proporcionar una respuesta correacta. Por dergracia tal y como esta planteada la pregunta en este momento apunta a ser cerrada.

Comment: gracias por la aportación me ayudo mucho saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la idea de una base de datos SQL es mantener toda la información relacionada, así que, lo más recomendable es mantener los productos en la tabla y manejar una columna de "estatus" (así como lo comentas) donde actives y desactives el producto.

Si eliminas un producto y haces uso de constraints, puedes eliminar las notas relacionadas con el producto.

Saludos!

Comment: gracias por la aportación me ayudo mucho saludos.